# Rotating videos with ffmpeg windows explorer extension

Tags: video, rotation, mp4

I would like to rotate my mp4 videos with this command `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=270 output.mp4` but add an explorer extension called something like `rotate ccw` so I can just right click on a file called ie `GH010235.MP4` select that option and it rotates the video, then adds it in the same folder, same filename but with _rotated added at the end so I would get ie `GH010235_rotated.MP4`

Alternatively I would like ffmpeg to process the entire folder. It should look for all *.mp4 rotate them and name them *_rotated.mp4 put them in the same folder or a subfolder \output. If possible with cmd not linux, phyton or w/e

Answer (score 0):

I take it you probably want to use cmd because you are on Windows. If you are on Windows you have powershell available. Thus I'll present solutions based on powershell.

---

### First solution

You can write a Powershell function for that:

```
function rotate_ccw {
    Param ([System.IO.FileInfo] $inputfile, [System.IO.FileInfo] $outputfile)
    ffmpeg -i $inputfile -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=270 $outputfile
}
```

The call would then look like this:

`rotate_ccs -inputfile input.mp4 -outputfile output.mp4`

**NOTE**: This solution should be selfexplaining. If there are any questions, please ask.

---

### Second solution

The solution to your looping approach would (also in powershell) be:

```
ls ./*.mp4 | foreach {ffmpeg -i "$_" -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=270 "$($_.basename)_rotated.mp4"}
```

`ls ./*.mp4`: Lists all *.mp4 files in the local directory.

`<command> | <command>`: The so calles pipe-operator takes the output from the first command and passes it as input to the second command.

`foreach {<do your stuff>}`: Self-explaining

`$_`: This references to the current file from the foreach-loop.